# Xamarin Firebase Auth não instala pelo NuGet

Tags: .net, firebase, xamarin-forms, auth

Bom dia amigos.
Estou iniciando um projeto em Xamarin Forms para iOS e Android, e vou usar o Firebase para Autenticação (Xamarin.Firebase.Auth).

Mas ao selecionar no gerenciador de pacotes (NuGet) o pacote Xamarin.Firebase.Auth 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Erro    NU1202  O pacote Xamarin.Firebase.Common 71.1610.0 não é compatível com netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1). O pacote Xamarin.Firebase.Common 71.1610.0 dá suporte a: monoandroid90 (MonoAndroid,Version=v9.0)
```

As versões são:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No Projeto do XamarinForms eu tenho apenas os pacotes

- FirebaseDatabase.net (4.0.4)
- Xamarin.Essentials (1.3.1)
- Xamarin.Forms (4.4.0.991265)

Pelo que entendi o Xamarin.Firebase.Common (requisito do Auth) não roda no NETStandard (2), e ele roda com Mono9

Como resolvo isso?

Para usar autenticação do Firebase no Xamarin Forms eu uso esse pacote mesmo Xamarin.Firebase.Common?

Obrigado desde já!

---

ATUALIZAÇÃO:

Após muitas tentativas, recriei o projeto e tentei passo a passo do zero, e recebi outras mensagens de erro com outros pacotes então percebi que não tem relação com o erro que postei acima. Como eu disse o projeto recriado estava funcionando normal, criei umas classes etc e compilei, fui almoçar e deu indigestão porque quando voltei e sentei no PC já estava com esse erro:
[image: FirebaseDatabase.net está instalado mas ele não tá reconhecendo]

Pelo que entendi alguma coisa tá acontecendo com o Nuget e ele está perdendo as referencias!

Veja que o pacote FirebaseDatabase.net (4.0.4) que ele está acusando que não foi encontrado está instalado como imagem abaixo:

[image: Xamarin.Firebase.Net]

Eu tentei entrar em Ferramentas\Opções\Gerenciador de Pacotes do NuGet e "Limpar todos os caches", sem sucesso!

Não entendo muito bem o que é o XamlCTask e o porque isso ocorre, alguma dica?

Estranho que no Projeto Xamarin.Forms ele não está encontrando nenhuma referencia:
[image: Namespaces não encontrados]

Obrigado novamente comunidade pelas ajudas de sempre!

Comment: Eu teria que usar uma versão mais antiga do Xamarin.Forms? Ou é NETStandard.Library?
Não tenho experiências com as versões e pacotes usados no XamarinForms, nem com Mono, não sei se estou usando o pacote certo para "Xamarin.Firebase.Auth", se tiver alguma alternativa aceito sugestões.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia!

Tenta atualizar o seu Mono.Android para 9 ou usar uma versão anterior do Xamarin.Firebase.Auth compatível com o Mono.Android 8.

Obs.: O pacote deve ser instalado no projeto específico.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atualizar o Mono.Android: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246580/xamarin-how-to-update-mono-android-version-to-resolve-dependencies

Comment: Tentei com ambos os pacotes dá o mesmo erro!

Comment: Tentei também mudar a versão do NetStandard.Library (2.0.3) para uma inferior mas dá na mesma!

Comment: Estas versões que postei acima do Xamarin.Forms funcionam com outra SDK além da NETStandard.Library, digo para arrumar essa incompatibilidade?
Ou preciso usar uma versão anterior do Xamarin?

Comment: Acho que você esta tentando instalar o pacote em um projeto compartilhado (NetStandard). Você tem que instalar esse pacote no projeto específico ***.Android.

Comment: Muito obrigado Daniel pelo suporte. Infelizmente eu ainda não consegui resolver mas tenho  um novo diagnóstico que anteriormente não tinha identificado. Acho que o problema não tem relação com o pacote em si (firebase) que estou tentando instalar, pelo jeito o lance é com o Nuget.
Veja minha pergunta vou atualiza-la com uma imagem atual.